# How to pick a subdocument with its id?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get a subdocument (nested in array) by its id, but I still get the whole document.

```
router.get("/book/:libraryid/:bookid", (req, res) => {
  Library.findOne({ _id: req.params.libraryid, "book._id": req.params.bookid})
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result); //shows all subdocument
    });
});
```

How can I just pick out the subdocument with its id?

Schema:

```
   {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "12345"
    },
    "libaryName": "A random libary",
    "Books": [       
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "1"
            }
            "bookTitle": "Example",
            "TotalPages": "500"                 
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "2"
            }
            "bookTitle": "Delete Me",
            "TotalPages": "400"                 
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Library and Books schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following and it should return you the document with only filtered book based on bookId.

```
router.get("/book/:libraryid/:bookid", (req, res) => {
  Library.findOne({ _id: req.params.libraryid}, {"books": {"$elemMatch": {_id: req.params.bookid}}})
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result); //shows all subdocument
    });
});
```